# Apache AliasMatch with Multiple Subdomains

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have the following virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName article.example.com
  AliasMatch "^/(.*)" "/var/www/html/article.php"
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName company.example.com
  AliasMatch "^/(.*)" "/var/www/html/company.php"
 </VirtualHost>
```

I would like to put everything under one virtual host like so:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.*
  AliasMatch "^(article|company)\.example\.*/(.*)" "/var/www/html/$1.php"
 </VirtualHost>
```

Is this possible? Do I have to use mod rewrite? I want map certain subdomains to related files on my server without changing the url. I want `article.example.com/test-article` to map to `article.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> AliasMatch "^(article|company)\.example\.*/(.*)" "/var/www/html/$1.php"
> ```

The `AliasMatch` directive matches against the requested URL-path (as you are doing in the first example), not the *hostname* (as you are trying to do here), so something like this will not match.

The obvious choice would be mod_rewrite, as you suggest. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(article|company)\.
RewriteRule ^ /var/www/html/%1.php [L]
```

Where the `%1` backreference contains the match from the captured subpattern in the preceding *CondPattern*.

If `/var/www/html` is the document root, then that can be omitted from the *substitution* string, rewriting to a document root-relative URL-path instead of an absolute file-path. ie. simply `/%1.php`.

You could make it more generic and rewrite the request for any subdomain where that subdomain exists as a `.php` file in the document root. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

Comment: Just trying to understand, so %1 takes the variables from the brackets? Also, why is ^ needed within the RewriteRule? Does the ^ take the string from the condition? Or is ^ just reference the entire string.

Comment: @MaciekSemik Yes, `%1` contains what is matched by the regex in the brackets, in the preceding _condition_ (_CondPattern_). In the same way `$1` would contain what is matched by a bracketed subpattern in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (just like `AliasMatch`). `^` matches against the requested URL-path - `^` is successful for everything (since we are rewriting every URL-path) - we do not need to actually match anything here. You could use `$` or `.` here instead, but `^` is my preference. eg. In your `AliasMatch` directive, you could have used `^` instead of `"^/(.*)"`, which is more efficient.